# Something wrong with the way the site loads

Tags: browser

I own a small blog and recently random people have been telling me that my site has loading problems as in the site will load but only pictures will show and not the text. I've never encountered the problem personally myself until today. I see what they mean, and if I hover my mouse over the text, then the text loads as well. Anybody have a clue on why?

Comment: Try disabling all your plugins and switching to a default theme (Twenty Thirteen or Twenty Fourteen, for instance). If the problem goes away, switch back to your existing theme. If the problem returns, there's something wrong with your theme. If not, turn on your plugins one by one, checking your site each time. If the problem returns, the last plugin you activated is the culprit.

Comment: Thanks! The problem is that I can't duplicate the problem myself. It only occurs sometime.

Comment: This is a **Browser/CSS** issue that is not *specific to WordPress*, and should be migrated.

Answer (score 1):

If it's happening only with Google Chrome, then it might be due to Google font's not rendering properly. Use this code in your style.css to fix the issue.

```
body {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.1s;
    -webkit-animation-name: fontfix;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.1s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fontfix {
    from { opacity: 1; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}
```

Sometimes, it didn't work too so the it'll be good by adding this code in your `header.php` file:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">


 $(function() { $('body').hide().show(); });
</script>




<script type="text/javascript">

//JavaScript goes here



WebFontConfig = {
  google: { families: ['FontOne', 'FontTwo'] },
    fontinactive: function (fontFamily, fontDescription) {
   //Something went wrong! Let's load our local fonts.
    WebFontConfig = {
      custom: { families: ['FontOne', 'FontTwo'],
      urls: ['font-one.css', 'font-two.css']
    }
  };
  loadFonts();
  }
};


function loadFonts() {
  var wf = document.createElement('script');
  wf.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https' : 'http') +
    '://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1/webfont.js';
  wf.type = 'text/javascript';
  wf.async = 'true';
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s);
}


(function () {
  //Once document is ready, load the fonts.
  loadFonts();
  })();


</script>
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Thank you so much! Yes it only happens in Google Chrome, but what happens is if I refresh the page it will load properly

Comment: Yes that's the problem most of people are having. Those two solutions might do the trick